# Unity: Load Image/Sprite on JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I want to load sprite on json but how ? Text are showing but not the images.

This is the JSON code to load my text data.

```
 private void myLoadGameData() //LOAD THE DATA
{
    string myfilePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, mygameDataFileName); //I THINK THIS IS THE PATH OF THE FILE

    if (File.Exists(myfilePath))
    {

        string mydataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(myfilePath); // READ THE FILE
        TSGameData myloadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<TSGameData>(mydataAsJson);  // TSGAME DATA IS A ANOTHER SCRIPT THAT HAVE AN ARRAY FOR THE DATA
        myRoundData = myloadedData.myRoundData;
    } //myRoundData IS A VARIABLE THAT HOLDS THE ARRAY OF TSROUNDDATA TO GET THE DATA
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
    }
}
```

> Here is my JSON script. I am not really sure if this is a valid script to load image.

```
"questionImage":"Assets/ImagesQuiz/NoentryPlate.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

To be a valid JSON, your text file content should be inside brackets, like this:

```
{ "questionImage":"Assets/ImagesQuiz/NoentryPlate.png" }
```

Please check JSON format documentation [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/).

Comment: Of course it is that is just the syntax any other solution?

Comment: I know the syntax just, I just pertaining into the syntax... those brackets are fine..

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation on loading images, also try using breakpoints to see whats being fed into the function and if that path actually exists (it looks like an absolute path, and if so most likely not going to work)

I imagine if there was a problem with the JSON you would get the relevant error about it, but seems more like miss-use of the function and/or improper file path

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `questionImage` is a property in the `myRoundData` variable, you would need to grab the string and use it as an asset path, Unity has a simple function to load assets by path

```
Resources.Load<T>(string path)
```

This function will return a loaded asset reference as the provided generic type. However, the `Resources.Load` method expects that all assets will be stored in a `Resources` folder in the `Assets` folder. You can have multiple `Resources` folders nested within various other folders. For example, you could have the following files

- Assets/Resources/Test1.png
- Assets/Resources/UI/Textures/Test2.png
- Assets/Images/Resources/Test3.png

Assuming their texture type is set to `Sprite`, each one could be accessed with

```
Resources.Load<Sprite>("Test1");
Resources.Load<Sprite>("UI/Textures/Test2");
Resources.Load<Sprite>("Test3");
```

A few things to note

- If you have files with the same name but in different resources
  folders, it will return the first resource found.
- You do not need to provide the file extension.
- You can nest files within folders, as long as long as one of its
  parent folders is a `Resources` folder. (See `Test2.png` in the
  example above)

With this approach, you first need to change the way you store your `questionImage` property value to something like this

```
{ "questionImage":"NoentryPlate" }
```

Then, with the code you provided, we could add an additional method to handle this resource loading and sprite setting part. We would need a reference to a GameObject with a `SpriteRenderer` component (you could create an empty gameObject and add the component yourself). Once you load the sprite, you can set the `sprite` property of the `SpriteRenderer` component to the sprite that you just loaded.

```
public SpriteRenderer MySprite;

private Sprite LoadedSprite = null;

private void myLoadGameData() //LOAD THE DATA
{
    string myfilePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, mygameDataFileName); //I THINK THIS IS THE PATH OF THE FILE

    if (File.Exists(myfilePath))
    {

        string mydataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(myfilePath); // READ THE FILE
        TSGameData myloadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<TSGameData>(mydataAsJson);  // TSGAME DATA IS A ANOTHER SCRIPT THAT HAVE AN ARRAY FOR THE DATA
        myRoundData = myloadedData.myRoundData;

        // vvv   CALL OUR NEW METHOD HERE   vvv
        LoadSprite(myRoundData.questionImage);
    } //myRoundData IS A VARIABLE THAT HOLDS THE ARRAY OF TSROUNDDATA TO GET THE DATA
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
    }
}

private void LoadSprite (string path)
{
    if (LoadedSprite != null)
        Resources.UnloadAsset(LoadedSprite);

    LoadedSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(path);

    MySprite.sprite = LoadedSprite;
}
```

Comment: questionImage is a property of my script QuestionData.cs it is an error from the code you've given any solutions? thanks

Comment: Wherever it is that you have access to that QuestionData object is where you will want to call the `LoadSprite` method outlined above.

For instance, let's assume you have a QuestionData variable named `myQuestionData`. Then you would call LoadSprite using the following


`LoadSprite(myQuestionData.questionImage);`

Comment: Hey dude I've try but there's an error saying "cannot convert from "UnityEngine.Sprite to string""

Comment: Does QuestionData contain the sprite itself or just the path to the sprite? If it contains the sprite itself, then you should be able to replace LoadSprite with the following:

`private void LoadSprite (Sprite sprite)
{
    MySprite.sprite = sprite;
}`

Comment: and where should I put these codes? Resources.Load<Sprite>("Test1");
Resources.Load<Sprite>("UI/Textures/Test2");
Resources.Load<Sprite>("Test3");   I am very sorry i'm new to json and unity :(

Comment: You shouldn't need those. As long as you already have the sprite reference, which it sounds like you do given the error you were getting in your 2nd comment, then you can just pass it into the revised `LoadSprite` method in my comment above.

Comment: Lol I don't know what is the problem but images are still not loading on the game :( I badly need those images.

Comment: The problem is the code on how to serialize json above.. I think there's something wrong I'm really confused right now :(

Comment: I've made it a solution ! Thank you ! your code works just fine :) I just changed it a little but it helps a lot